# Typescript and mongoose returning "any" type on find queries

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to integrate mongoose with typescript:

UserModel.ts:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, Model } from "mongoose";


interface IUserSchema extends Document {
  userId: number;
  email: string;
  passwordHash: string;
  passwordSalt: string;
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  userId: Number,
  email: String,
  passwordHash: String,
  passwordSalt: String,
});

export default mongoose.model<IUserSchema>("User", UserSchema);
```

userRouter.ts

```
import UserModel from "./UserModel";
...

userRouter.get("/:userId", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const userId = parseInt(req.params.userId);
  const myUser = await UserModel.findOne({ userId }).exec();
});

...
```

The problem is that `myUser` constant has `any` type while it should have `IUserSchema` type

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you finish with `.exec()`?

Comment: Your code looks right and works fine in the TS Playground, but I have seen other questions about this specific issue where VSCode was not interpreting the document type even though typescript was.